# How set Django foreign key with it own id

Tags: django, orm

Example My post belong to a user Post->User so if I want the post, I have to use.

```
class Post(model.Model):
       creator = model.ForeignKey("some user model here",on_delete=model.CASCADE)
       //SOME OTHER FIELDS
```

/user/iamadog/post/999

So I want just to use

/post/1234 or
/post/1234-is-the-best-password

How to set my model like that?

EDIT 1 Adds exmaple model

Comment: Include your model definitions and clearer requirements. Question does not make any sense without the code and ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please read about Django urls. Then you will understand. Or ask question specifically

Comment: Edited 1 : Add code.   I am confused about id or pk thing